# Firebase cloud messaging stopped with upgrade to Oreo

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo

I was just getting started with Android development and managed to get Firebase messaging working after running the wizard.  I was able to receive background notifications on my Nexus 5X running Nougat.  But then my 5X upgraded to Oreo and Firebase notifications haven't worked since.  I've heard about background execution limitations, but since I'm just getting started I don't know what I actually have to do to get it working again.  Are there any write ups on this?  I tried a new project from scratch hoping the wizard had been updated, but no change.  I was using application broadcast messages and topic subscription messages, no device token used.

Comment: Have you reviewed: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html and what priority are you sending messages: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

Comment: I did read that, but it was hard to figure out what I actually might need to do.  Also one of the migration points is to use FCM to selectively wake up the application to receive the messages and I thought that was what I was doing in the first place, so I don't see why it isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use a recent version of the FCM sdk.

FCM sdk introduced support for Android O in April, if you are using older version your app would not receive messages in Android O and could potentially crash.

See the latest release here: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

PS: firebase SDK has been moved to the Google Maven repository.
Be sure to check out the latest instructions here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase

Comment: My Firebase dependency line is:
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1
The SDK manager says I'm fully up to date, and Android Studio says I'm on the latest version.  If there's a newer version of anything I don't know how I'd be supposed to find out about it.

Comment: current version is 11.4.2 and minor releases are published every 2 weeks

Comment: So the Firebase assistant wizard hasn't been updated to fetch the new version?

Comment: I am not sure about that. It's possible it depends on a different Android Studio version ? It would be great if you could report as a bug in to Firebase Support.

Comment: Thank you!  Just got it working.  Seems like the wizard needs to be kept up to date.  I had to change the Google services line to:
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
which didn't work until I added the maven repo:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }

    }
}
And then I could add:
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'

Comment: I have been told that the new version of the Firebase Assistant is available in Android Studio beta. Hopefully it will be soon be promoted to stable. Thanks for your bug report.

Answer (score 8):

**When you target Android 8.0 (API level 26), you must implement one or more notification channels to display notifications to your users**. If you don't target Android 8.0 (API level 26) but your app is used on devices running Android 8.0 (API level 26), your app behaves the same as it would on devices running Android 7.1 (API level 25) or lower.

If you change your target version into Android 8.0 (API level 26), you have to do the following change

```
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     String id = "id_product";//This will be enter when creating Builder
     // The user-visible name of the channel.
     CharSequence name = "Product";
     // The user-visible description of the channel.
     String description = "Notifications regarding our products";
     int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX;
     NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
     // Configure the notification channel.
     mChannel.setDescription(description);
     mChannel.enableLights(true);
     // Sets the notification light color for notifications posted to this
     // channel, if the device supports this feature.
     mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
     notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
  }
```

Change your Builder constructor

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, **ID you have put in the Notification Channel**)
```

Finally you can create the notification from the Builder

```
notificationManager.notify("0", notificationBuilder.build())
```

Ref: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels

Comment: After doing this also the Token is coming null when running the app in mobile of Android API lower than 27.

Comment: This code will generate notification, if you want to get token you have to override onNewToken(String token) in FirebaseMessagingService.